# Overrride serif and sans-serif with @font-face

Tags: css, unicode, font-face

Is there any way to use `@font-face` to override generic fallback fonts like `serif` and `sans-serif`? For context, I'm trying to use the `unicode-range:` attribute to change how certain characters are shown, and this works fine when I override a default font like Helvetica or something similar:

```
// MyStyle.css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  src: local("my-better-font.tff");
  unicode-range: U+26;
}
```

If the remote webpage (which I don't have control over) uses something like the following:

```
// Webpage.css
p { font-family: "Helvetica"; }
```

Then I can change how the ampersand is displayed. However, if instead the website has something like `p { font-family: sans-serif; }`, attempting to create a new font-face whose family is `sans-serif` doesn't seem to work. Is there anyway to use a unicode-range selector in this case?

Comment: No, you can't override whatever font the browser uses for keywords like `sans-serif`. However, if you can use `@font-face`, what's preventing you from using `font-family` as well?

Comment: If you import your own font, what's the matter on overriding default browser fonts?